# react navigation const file get params

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-tabnavigator

I'm new to React Native, i'm trying to create app with tab-navigation, but i'm i cant find a way to get params from previous page (i'm using StackNavigator) from const TabNavigation component. here's my code:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { TabNavigator } from "react-navigation";

import Page1 from './tab/page1.js';
import Page2 from './tab/page2.js';

const Tab = TabNavigator({
    Page1: { screen: Page1 },
    Page2: { screen: Page2 },
  },
  {
    tabBarPosition: "bottom",
    swipeEnabled: false,
    animationEnabled: false,
    }
  }
);

export default Tab;
```

and i'm trying todo this way, but it cause the app cannot navigate to other page from inside Page1 or Page2

```js
class Base extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
 this.state = { notif: 0 };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({ notif: this.props.navigation.state.params.notif })
  }

  render() {
 return (
      <Tab/>
    );
  }
}

export default Tab;
```

Thank You.

Comment: 1. First: You need to learn this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params.html

Answer (score 0):

This is how you pass params in `react-navigation` from one screen to another.

```
navigate('screen_name',{param_key:param_value})
```

and in the next screen extract params like this

```
const {params} = this.props.navigation.state

const value_from_previous_screen = params.param_key
```

Comment: Yeah, i understand this, but i cannot figured out in where i shoud put `const {params} = this.props.navigation.state` in the first code that i share above, because it cause `error: undefine is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation')`

Comment: Are you navigating to the Base screen ?

Comment: Yes, i navigate to base screen and send params into it, but i dont know how to get params in base screen

Comment: Please share your full code where you are navigating to the other screen and the code where you have added Base class to your stack navigator